# Cannot find Instance Manager when trying to add second CF site on ColdFusion 9 Admin panel

Tags: coldfusion, multiple-instances

Now perhaps I am just dense and cannot figure this out, but i cannot for the life of me find the Instance manage on ColdFusion 9 Standard. I do know that it is a multi-server installation as it is already running 2 CF sites, but i am trying to add a third and cannot figure it out. There is no Enterprise Manager on the left panel nor Instance manager. Sorry if I sound like a complete idiot but where is this and why can't I find it??

Comment: Are you on the first instance, or the second instance you created?  I believe it only appears on the original "cfusion" instance.

Comment: As Henry mentioned in his answer, running multiple CF instances is not available under Standard. That is why you cant find the options in the admin panels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK Standard edition does NOT allow multi-instance.  You will only see that in the free Developer or pricey Enterprise edition.

To run multiple CF App under the same instance, you can do multiple Application.cfc (logical application) and map them in your web server respectively by webroot.  They will be sharing the same CF instance, but at least your Session / Application scope won't be mixed up if you give each Application.cfc a different `this.name`.

Comment: Thanks Henry. Brought into an existing setup and it just didn't make sense to me for a bit there.

Comment: @Larson ok, does it make sense now?

Comment: Yea, I just had to do the multiple apps like you said. This is my 3rd month working with CF after a some years in .Net so it's just a bit of an adjustment lol. It's up now, though. +1 for the help!